# Why do you have to explicitly specify scope with friendly_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, scope, nested, friendly-id

I'm using the friendly_id gem. I also have my routes nested:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.resources :users do |user|
  user.resources :events
end
```

So I have URLs like `/users/nfm/events/birthday-2009`.

In my models, I want the event title to be scoped to the username, so that both `nfm` and `mrmagoo` can have events `birthday-2009` without them being slugged.

```
# app/models/event.rb
def Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :title, :use_slug => true, :scope => :user
  belongs_to :user

  ...
end
```

I'm also using `has_friendly_id :username` in my User model.

However, in my controller, I'm only pulling out events pertinent to the user who is logged in (current_user):

```
def EventsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...
end
```

This doesn't work; I get the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound; expected scope but got none`.

```
# This works
@event = current_user.events.find(params[:id], :scope => 'nfm')

# This doesn't work, even though User has_friendly_id, so current_user.to_param _should_ return "nfm"
@event = current_user.events.find(params[:id], :scope => current_user)

# But this does work!
@event = current_user.events.find(params[:id], :scope => current_user.to_param)
```

*SO*, why do I need to explicitly specify :scope if I'm restricting it to current_user.events anyway? And why does current_user.to_param need to be called explicitly? Can I override this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with friendly_id 2.2.7 but when I updated to friendly_id 3.0.4 in my Rails 2.3.5 app, everything works. I have test all 4 find invocations you mentioned in my app and they work.

Something to take note of are a few API changes that may affect you. The ones I ran into were:

- `:strip_diacritics` has been replaced with `:strip_non_ascii`.

  I decided to switch to Stringex's `String#to_url` instead by overriding `normalize_friendly_id`
- `resource.has_better_id?` is now `!resource.friendly_id_status.best?`
- `resource.found_using_numeric_id?` is now `resource.friendly_id_status.numeric?`